# XSLT 1.0: Surrounded tag with following-sibling conditions

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xslt-1.0, lxml

I try to surround with a tag author : (surname and forename) tags when they are direct following sibling. If it is not sorted in this way just surrounded directly the tag (forename or surname). This tags are specified by a specific attribute (bilbo). All tags get a default namespaces and I need to use XSLT 1.0.

This is my xml input.

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
<surname> Amblard </surname>
      <bibl>
          <surname bilbo="True"> Amblard </surname>
          <forename bilbo="True"> F. </forename>
          <c bilbo="True"> , </c>
          <forename bilbo="True"> P. </forename>
          <title>titre</title>
          <surname bilbo="True"> Amblard </surname>
  </bibl>
</TEI>
```

This is my xsl file:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   
   xmlns:tei = "http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">   
   <xsl:template match = "@*|node()"> 
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="tei:surname[@bilbo]">
    <xsl:element name="author" namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*[1][self::forename and @bilbo]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="tei:forename[@bilbo]">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::surname and @bilbo])">
        <xsl:element name="author" namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is :

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
   <surname> Amblard </surname>
      <bibl>
          <author>
         <surname bilbo="True"> Amblard </surname>
      </author>
          <author>
         <forename bilbo="True"> F. </forename>
      </author>
          <c bilbo="True"> , </c>
          <author>
         <forename bilbo="True"> P. </forename>
      </author><title>titre</title>
          <author>
     <surname bilbo="True"> Amblard </surname>
  </author>
  </bibl>
</TEI>
```

But expected output should be:

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
   <surname> Amblard </surname>
      <bibl>
          <author>
         <surname bilbo="True"> Amblard </surname>
         <forename bilbo="True"> F. </forename>
      </author>
          <c bilbo="True"> , </c>
          <author>
         <forename bilbo="True"> P. </forename>
      </author><title>titre</title>
          <author>
     <surname bilbo="True"> Amblard </surname>
  </author>
  </bibl>
</TEI>
```

Note that this post follows a previous ticket: ([xslt transform and lxml python problem to handle namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57147248/xslt-transform-and-lxml-python-problem-to-handle-namespace). Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite difficult to understand. And if I do understand the required logic correctly, it is an awful lot of work to implement in **XSLT 1.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- leading surname -->
<xsl:template match="tei:surname[@bilbo][following-sibling::*[1][self::tei:forename]]" priority="1">
     <xsl:element name="author" namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
        <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::tei:forename[1][@bilbo]"/>
     </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- leading forename -->
<xsl:template match="tei:forename[@bilbo][following-sibling::*[1][self::tei:surname]]" priority="1">
     <xsl:element name="author" namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
        <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::tei:surname[1][@bilbo]"/>
     </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- surname or forename, standalone -->
<xsl:template match="tei:surname[@bilbo] | tei:forename[@bilbo]">
     <xsl:element name="author" namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- trailing surname -->
<xsl:template match="tei:surname[@bilbo][preceding-sibling::*[1][self::tei:forename]]"/>

<!-- trailing forename -->
<xsl:template match="tei:forename[@bilbo][preceding-sibling::*[1][self::tei:surname]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Perhaps it would be simpler to approach this using *sibling recursion*. But that would mean changing the given rules, applying the logic to `surname`s and `forename`s within the `bibl` parent, rather than using the `bilbo` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right in XSLT1.0 it is not easy but I use lxml library and it does not handle XSLT2.0. Unfortunatly changing the given rules is not possible, only the attribute bilbo is a specific marker.

Comment: @Mikael.hork257k, just note that if you mix tag with attribute bilbo and without as 
 <bibl><surname bilbo="True"> Amblard </surname><forename>Mathieu </forename><bibl>
You get a wrong result with your xsl proposal.

Comment: @mathieu If that's a problem, add the `[@bilbo]` predicate to the following-sibling node.